# make: *** [Makefile:20: run] Error 17

Tags: symfony, docker-compose

Soy nueva en docker y estoy configurando el entorno para mi api. Tengo mi archivo docker-compose yml y otras dos carpetas necesarias para mi proyecto (nginx y php). Cuando ejecuto make run, solo se me crea una imagen, pero el volumen, el container y la carpeta de la base de datos NO se me crearon. Tambien tengo el error "unable to prepare context: path "./docker/database" not found"

1. archivo docker-compose yml

```
    version: '3.5'
    
    # --------------------- SERVICIOS PARA LA WEB --------------------------- #
    services:
      symfony-api-platform-web:
        container_name: symfony-api-platform-web
        build:
          context: ./docker/nginx
          args:
            UID: $U_ID
        ports:
          - 250:80
        volumes:
          - ./public:/appdata/www/public
        depends_on:
          - symfony-api-platform-be
        networks:
          - symfony-api-platform-network
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #   
    
    #--------------------- SERVICIOS DEL INTERPRETE DE PHP ----------------- #
      symfony-api-platform-be:
        container_name: symfony-api-platform-be
        build:
          context: docker/php
          args:
            UID: $U_ID
        environment:
          PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=Docker
          PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED: 1
          XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=172.17.0.1 remote_port=9005 # Linux users
        #      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_port=9005 # MacOS users
        volumes:
          - ./:/appdata/www
          - ./docker/php/xdebug-linux.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
          #      - ./docker/php/xdebug-macos.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
          - ~/.ssh/id_rsa:/home/appuser/.ssh/id_rsa
        depends_on:
          - symfony-api-platform-db
        networks:
          - symfony-api-platform-network
    
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------- #
    
    # ------------------------- SERVICIOS PARA LA BD ------------------------ #
    
      symfony-api-platform-db:
        container_name: symfony-api-platform-db
        image: mysql:8.0
        build:
          context: ./docker/database
        ports:
          - 36000:3306
          # el primer puerto es LOCAL , el segundo del CONTENEDOR
    
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony_db
          MYSQL_USER: root
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        command: mysqld --sql_mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
        volumes:
          - symfony-api-platform-db-data:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
          - symfony-api-platform-network
    
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------- #
    
    volumes:
      symfony-api-platform-db-data:
    
    networks:
      symfony-api-platform-network:
        external: true
```

2. archivo Makefile

```
    DOCKER_BE = symfony-api-platform-be
    OS := $(shell uname)
    
    ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
        UID = $(shell id -u)
    else ifeq ($(OS),Linux)
        UID = $(shell id -u)
    else
        UID = 1000
    endif
    
    help: ## Show this help message
        @echo 'usage: make [target]'
        @echo
        @echo 'targets:'
        @egrep '^(.+)\:\ ##\ (.+)' ${MAKEFILE_LIST} | column -t -c 2 -s ':#'
    
    run: ## Start the containers
        docker network create symfony-api-platform-network || true
        U_ID=${UID} docker-compose up -d
    
    stop: ## Stop the containers
        U_ID=${UID} docker-compose stop
    
    restart: ## Restart the containers
        $(MAKE) stop && $(MAKE) run
    
    build: ## Rebuilds all the containers
        U_ID=${UID} docker-compose build
    
    prepare: ## Runs backend commands
        $(MAKE) composer-install
    
    # Backend commands
    composer-install: ## Installs composer dependencies
        U_ID=${UID} docker exec --user ${UID} -it ${DOCKER_BE} composer install --no-scripts --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader
    
    migrations: ## Runs the migrations
        U_ID=${UID} docker exec -it --user ${UID} ${DOCKER_BE} bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate -n
    
    be-logs: ## Tails the Symfony dev log
        U_ID=${UID} docker exec -it --user ${UID} ${DOCKER_BE} tail -f var/log/dev.log
    # End backend commands
    
    ssh-be: ## ssh's into the be container
        U_ID=${UID} docker exec -it --user ${UID} ${DOCKER_BE} bash
    
    code-style: ## Runs php-cs to fix code styling following Symfony rules
        U_ID=${UID} docker exec -it --user ${UID} ${DOCKER_BE} php-cs-fixer fix src --rules=@Symfony
        U_ID=${UID} docker exec -it --user ${UID} ${DOCKER_BE} php-cs-fixer fix tests --rules=@Symfony
    
    generate-ssh-keys: ## Generates SSH keys for the JWT library
        U_ID=${UID} docker exec -it --user ${UID} ${DOCKER_BE} mkdir -p config/jwt
        U_ID=${UID} docker exec -it --user ${UID} ${DOCKER_BE} openssl genrsa -passout pass:767b453a97ac019714eb7ccbce781d16 -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 4096
        U_ID=${UID} docker exec -it --user ${UID} ${DOCKER_BE} openssl rsa -pubout -passin pass:767b453a97ac019714eb7ccbce781d16 -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Encuentro los archivos similares a los de un curso en Udemy "Guía definitiva para crear APIs con Symfony 5 y API Platform". Mi respuesta será pensando en que estás tomando ese curso.

Yo también tuve las mismas problemáticas (y otras más) siguiendo ese curso.

Con esos archivos intentas ejecutar comandos de docker y linux que dependen de la existencia de otros archivos y carpetas.

Muy probablemente estes copiando la configuracion del docker-compose.yml y Makefile de la rama **master** del [repositorio del curso](https://github.com/juanwilde/symfony-api-platform/), esa rama se encuentra actualizada a la finalizacion del curso y tu estas en el inicio.

Necesitas copiar la configuracion de la rama [section4/docker-configuration](https://github.com/juanwilde/symfony-api-platform/tree/section4/docker-configuration).

1.- docker-compose.yml es igual

2.- Makefile

```
#!/bin/bash

DOCKER_BE = symfony-api-platform-be
OS := $(shell uname)

ifeq ($(OS),Darwin)
    UID = $(shell id -u)
else ifeq ($(OS),Linux)
    UID = $(shell id -u)
else
    UID = 1000
endif

help: ## Show this help message
    @echo 'usage: make [target]'
    @echo
    @echo 'targets:'
    @egrep '^(.+)\:\ ##\ (.+)' ${MAKEFILE_LIST} | column -t -c 2 -s ':#'

run: ## Start the containers
    docker network create symfony-api-platform-network || true
    U_ID=${UID} docker-compose up -d

stop: ## Stop the containers
    U_ID=${UID} docker-compose stop

restart: ## Restart the containers
    $(MAKE) stop && $(MAKE) run

build: ## Rebuilds all the containers
    U_ID=${UID} docker-compose build

prepare: ## Runs backend commands
    $(MAKE) composer-install

# Backend commands
composer-install: ## Installs composer dependencies
    U_ID=${UID} docker exec --user ${UID} -it ${DOCKER_BE} composer install --no-scripts --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader

migrations: ## Runs the migrations
    U_ID=${UID} docker exec -it --user ${UID} ${DOCKER_BE} bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate -n

be-logs: ## Tails the Symfony dev log
    U_ID=${UID} docker exec -it --user ${UID} ${DOCKER_BE} tail -f var/log/dev.log
# End backend commands

ssh-be: ## ssh's into the be container
    U_ID=${UID} docker exec -it --user ${UID} ${DOCKER_BE} bash

code-style: ## Runs php-cs to fix code styling following Symfony rules
    U_ID=${UID} docker exec -it --user ${UID} ${DOCKER_BE} php-cs-fixer fix src --rules=@Symfony
```